# What difference between throttleLatest and throttleLast in rxjava?

Tags: java, rx-java2, reactivex

In Observable, there are two methods called throttleLast and throttleLatest.

- [throttleLast javadoc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#throttleLast-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-)
- [throttleLatest javadoc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#throttleLatest-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-)

Marble diagrams are similar, but the two internal codes are different.

```java
public final Observable<T> throttleLast(long intervalDuration, TimeUnit unit) {
    return sample(intervalDuration, unit);
}


public final Observable<T> sample(long period, TimeUnit unit, Scheduler scheduler, boolean emitLast) {
    ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(unit, "unit is null");
    ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(scheduler, "scheduler is null");
    return RxJavaPlugins.onAssembly(new ObservableSampleTimed<T>(this, period, unit, scheduler, emitLast));
}
```

```java
public final Observable<T> throttleLatest(long timeout, TimeUnit unit, Scheduler scheduler, boolean emitLast) {
    ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(unit, "unit is null");
    ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(scheduler, "scheduler is null");
    return RxJavaPlugins.onAssembly(new ObservableThrottleLatest<T>(this, timeout, unit, scheduler, emitLast));
}
```

What difference between them?

Comment: Not positive, but `throttleLast` might operate on fixed time intervals and `throttleLatest` resets the timeout whenever an item arrives. In other words, the difference between _fixed rate_ and _fixed delay_.

Comment: It's in the javadoc: throttleLatest "If no items were emitted from the upstream during this timeout phase, the next upstream item is emitted immediately and the timeout window starts from then.". ThrottleLast emits at a fixed rate and if there is no item, nothing is emitted.

Answer (score 6):

See comments of @Slaw and @akarnokd.

> Not positive, but throttleLast might operate on fixed time intervals and throttleLatest **resets the timeout** whenever an item arrives. In other words, the difference between **fixed rate and fixed delay**.

And

> It's in the javadoc: throttleLatest "If no items were emitted from the upstream during this timeout phase, the next upstream item is emitted immediately and the timeout window starts from then.". ThrottleLast emits at a fixed rate and if there is no item, nothing is emitted.

I did not understand well, so I tried to compare myself.

[sample code](https://github.com/galcyurio/difference-between-throttleLatest-and-throttleLast)

[image: sample]

Comment: Ok, and what actually **is** the difference? What makes these two columns differ?

Comment: @mate00 There is no delay in throttleLatest. And throttleLatest resets the timeout whenever an item arrives.

Answer (score 4):

They are very similar.
They both have a fixed time window (the comments above on that are wrong).

The only difference is how the first item is handled.

- `ThrottleLast` will NOT immediately emit the first item, it will always wait for the time window to pass and then emit the last value from that time window (if any)
- `ThrottleLatest` will immediately emit the first item and after that it will behave the same as ThrottleLast.